# Router Resolver not rendering component

Tags: angular, angular-component-router, angular-resolver

I have this router resolver to retrieve data from the Google Firestore. I am trying to use the Resolver to fetch the data ahead. When I place debugger at resolve function it shows me the data retrieved from the Server. But it is never returning from the resolve() method. Can anyone please help me out.

**Routing Module**

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent},
    { path: 'projects', component: ProjectsComponent, resolve: {projectData: ProjectResolver} },
    { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent}
];
```

**App Module**

```
  providers: [
    ProjectService,
    ProjectResolver
  ],
```

**Resolver Service**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Resolve } from '@angular/router';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';
import { map } from "rxjs/operators";
import { Project } from './project.model';

@Injectable()
export class ProjectResolver implements Resolve<Project[]> {

    constructor(private projectService: ProjectService ) {

    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, router: RouterStateSnapshot) : Observable<Project[]> | any{
        return this.projectService.getProjects().pipe(map(project => {
            return project //Debugger shows fetched data(Array of projects)
        }
        ));
    }
}
```

**Project Service**

```
import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";

@Injectable()
export class ProjectService {

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {}

    getProjects(): Observable<any> {
        return this.db.collection('currentProjects').valueChanges();
    }

}
```

** Project Component (*This component in never loaded by Resolver*
)**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Project } from './project.model';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ProjectService } from './project.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-projects',
  templateUrl: './projects.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./projects.component.css']
})

export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

   projects: Project[] = [];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private projectService: ProjectService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      this.route.data.subscribe((data: Project[]) => {
        this.projects = data['projectData'];
      })
  }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the Angular Firebase Observable(event stream) will never complete like normal "observable" so it is never resolving. I modified the Observable with the "take" operator to get the first item and forced to complete.

```
this.db.collection('currentProjects').valueChanges().take(1);
```

Changes:

- Removed  ProjectService
- Modified ProjectResolver
- Modified ProjectComponent

I posted the solution to my problem below:

**Project Resolver (Working)**

```
export class ProjectResolver implements Resolve<any> {

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {

    }

    resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, router: RouterStateSnapshot) : any{

        return Observable.from(this.db.collection('currentProjects').valueChanges()
            .do(data => {  
                return data
            }).take(1))
    }
}
```

**Project Component(Working)**

```
export class ProjectsComponent implements OnInit {

  private projects: Project[];

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe((data) => {
      this.projects = data['projectData'];
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: It says that I need to wait for 2 days as I'm a new user

Answer (score 0):

Fetch data like `this.route.snapshot.data` instead of `this.route.data` and no need to subscribe to it

```
ngOnInit() {          
   this.projects = this.route.snapshot.data['projectData'];
}
```

Comment: why don't you add some small explanation as to why should it work and what was wrong with OP's approach?

Comment: The problem is ngOnInit() is never getting invoked. It is never getting past Resolver

Comment: @PopStack And also you should be providing `ProjectResolver` inside `app-routing module` as opposed to `app-module`. Because that is intended only to routing module.

Comment: @AmitChigadani Tried but nothing shows up. The only way I could force it render is by "return Observable.of(null)" in the Resolver. Also, nothing shows up in the console and I'm using Augury for debugging.