# Angular RouteResolver works only without delay, has issues with observable

Tags: angular, angular-router

When using the `resolve :{ key : ResolverService}` to resolve some data for the component, if the `ResolverService` returns some data immediately (without using observable or promise), the component is loaded as expected on the UI. But, if the resolver is returning Observable, then it is not working, even when the observable gets its next value;

Example on stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-delayed-resolver-issue

The logic for returning observable in guard and resolver is the same, but the resolve doesn't seem to work for some reason.

Already checked this [Router Resolver not rendering component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047800/router-resolver-not-rendering-component) , didn't help much.

Any help for the given scenario is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The observable returned by the resolver must *complete*. Yours never complete, so the navigation never happens.

A simpler way of defininig your delayed observable (that would complete) would be to use the delay pipe:

```
return of('data from delayed').pipe(delay(1000));
```

Comment: check the updated file, I used observer.complete(). to do it. https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-delayed-resolver-issue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdelayed.resolver.service.ts

Comment: @SachinGupta yes, you can of course do that. But it's much less elegant and concise than what I suggest using in my answer.

Comment: I agree, but `rxjs` imports have messed up my brain.

Comment: It's actually simple: everything (types, factory functions, like Observable, of) is imported from 'rxjs', except operators, (i.e. everything you put inside pipe(), like delay) which are imported from 'rxjs/operators').